# Test class for a batch - variable does not exist

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, error

I wrote a test class for my batchable class. It works great but I want to limit the query of the test class only to the test object I have created.

So I have this inside my test method:

```
String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, ShipmentQuantity__c, CurrentQuantity__c FROM Stock__c WHERE Id =: ' + testStock.Id;
```

And then my test.StartTest():

```
system.test.startTest();
Database.executeBatch(new IndependentBatch(query));
system.test.stopTest();
```

The error I get is

> "System.QueryException: Variable does not exist: a0236000001bOXdAAM".

Obviously it sees the ID but I don't understand what the error means. If I erase the `Where Id =: ' + testStock.Id;` the test runs like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up your variables. When you use merge syntax in SOQL, you must use the name of an existing variable in your scope. So if you had a variable called `stockId`, you could use: `'WHERE Id = :stockId'`. You can't do any cross-references, though, so `stock.Id` cannot be merged in.

However, if you use `'WHERE Id = :'' + stockId`, you get a resulting query string of `'WHERE Id = :a0236000001bOXdAAM'`. Since you do not have a variable called `a0236000001bOXdAAM`, you get an error.

Comment: I didn't think about that. You are correct! Thanks again for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `:` in a query, it causes the runtime engine to attempt to resolve a variable in the local scope. In other words, it's looking for a variable named `a0236000001bOXdAAM`. This binding occurs when Database.query, Database.queryCount, or Database.search is called with string parameter.

Instead, you'll need to quote the value correctly:

```
String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, ShipmentQuantity__c, CurrentQuantity__c FROM Stock__c WHERE Id = \'' + testStock.Id + '\'';
```